# How to centre class='wrap'

Tags: html, css, web

I'm currently working on my portfolio page and I've encountered some problems. How can I centre the portfolio part and still maintain its appearance (3 columns)?

HTML code:

```
<div class="wrap" style="background-color:#FAFAFA; height: 850px;">
      <div id="portfolio-container"class="portfolio" style="position: relative; height:850px; left:6%; right: 6%;">
        <div class="word" style="position: absolute; left:355px;">
          <h1> P O R T F O L I O </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top:100px;">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <a href="websitelink">
              <img class="img-responsive" width="300" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/1v5ifV5.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2>itemname</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="position: absolute; left: 325px; top:100px;">
          <div class="hovereffect">
             <a href="websitelink">
              <img class="img-responsive" width="300" src="http://i.imgur.com/KZvRuzf.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2>itemname</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="position: absolute; left: 640px; top:100px;">
          <div class="hovereffect">
             <a href="websitelink">
              <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/uWGHWMJ.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2>itemname</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top:370px;">
          <div class="hovereffect">
             <a href="websitelink">
              <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Rvi73Kd.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2>itemname</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="position: absolute; left: 325px; top:520px;">
          <div class="hovereffect">
             <a href="websitelink">
              <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/8uhmKFS.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2>itemname</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="position: absolute; left: 640px; top:350px;">
          <div class="hovereffect">
             <a href="websitelink">
              <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zLpahWP.jpg" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2>itemname</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

CSS Code (Didn't include the hover image part)

```
.portfolio {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0px;
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: 15.5%;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Looks like you don't close a lot of anchor tags

Comment: Also, could you please provide a live example reproducing the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d6ej7xaL/

Comment: What's the problem? The header is showing up fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e6zjj2yd/

Comment: Ok; thanks. Let me try to style it

Comment: yes but the whole container is not centered

Comment: Will this work @youknowwho: https://jsbin.com/subowugizo/edit?output

Comment: Thanks the title is now centered but the photos are not :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really able to help right now - play around with the widths and left/rights

Answer (score 0):

Remove style in Html code
HTML Code will be:

```
<div class="wrap" style="background-color:#ddd; height: 850px;">
  <div id="portfolio-container"class="portfolio">
    <div class="word">
      <h1> P O R T F O L I O </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <a href="websitelink">
          <img class="img-responsive" width="300" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/1v5ifV5.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>itemname</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
         <a href="websitelink">
          <img class="img-responsive" width="300" src="http://i.imgur.com/KZvRuzf.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>itemname</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
         <a href="websitelink">
          <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/uWGHWMJ.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>itemname</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
         <a href="websitelink">
          <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/Rvi73Kd.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>itemname</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
         <a href="websitelink">
          <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/8uhmKFS.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>itemname</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
         <a href="websitelink">
          <img width="300" class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/zLpahWP.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2>itemname</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

& CSS will be:

```
.wrap{text-align: center;}
.col-lg-3.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```